# Document.onclick() не работает

Tags: javascript

При нажатие `Document.onclick()` работает только `Button 2`, а при нажатие `document.onclick()` вообще не закроется в чем проблема?

```js
var s = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    first(s[i], i); //Работает только Button 2.
    //second(s[i], i); Работает нормально.
}

function first(e, i) {
    document.onclick = function(o) {
        o.stopPropagation();
        if (o.target == e || e.contains(o.target)) {
            alert('Открылся Select!');
        } else {
            alert('Закрылся Select!');
        }
    }
}
function second(e, i) {
    e.onclick = function(o) {
        o.stopPropagation();
        if (o.target == e || e.contains(o.target)) {
            alert('Открылся Select!');
        } else {
            alert('Закрылся Select!');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
```

**UPDATE**

При нажатие Button должно Открываться Select, а document наоборот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал так но все ровно не работает!

```
document.onclick = function(o) {
    o.stopPropagation();
    o.preventDefault();
    var s = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (o.target == s[i] || s[i].contains(o.target)) {
            alert('Открылся Select!');
        } else {
            alert('Закрылся Select!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если быть откровенным, стало любопытно, в чем суть данной конструкции....

Comment: @Air обновил вопрос

Comment: @Air как сделать чтобы ТОЛЬКО при нажатие `Button 1` и `Button 2` открывать `Select`, а в другом случае закрывать `Select`

Comment: Сейчас комп занят, пишу с другого, поэтому протестировать не могу. Попробуйте

Comment: Я не профи, но мне просто интересно реализовать это, но я не могу понять, за чем ты `select` с кнопки пытаешься открыть, это у тебя кастомный `select`?  И еще, просто у тебя в вопросе не понятно, ты с кнопки открываешь `select`, я так понимаю, что каждая кнопка должна открывать свой  `select`, а остальные закрываться, а кликом на `document` закрывать все   `select`? Я правильно понял?

Comment: @Air я выбрал Button для примера может быть div и т. д. `Каждая кнопка должна открывать свой select, а кликом на document закрывать все select` да так точно

Comment: @Air может быть любой элемент, да правильно это не стандартный `<select></select>`, а `<div class="select"></div>`

Comment: Ок...  Но на будущее, знай, вопрос надо оформлять, так, что бы в комментариях не приходилось выяснять обстоятельства и всякие подробности...

Comment: @Air хорошо! Вы можете помогать мне, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Air спасибо вам

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В общем я бы реализовал так....

```js
const select = document.querySelectorAll('.select');
const button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    for (var ii = 0; ii < select.length; ii++) {
      select[ii].classList.remove('active');

    }
    select[i].classList.add('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
}
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    select[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<div class="select">Допустим это select1</div>
<div class="select">Допустим это select2</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 3):

> в чем проблема?

Вы же вызвали функцию `first` `s.length` раз. Каждый раз с новым `e`. Естественно, в результате `document.onclick` имеет значение равное функции с замыканием, соответствующим последнему `e`.

Возможно, Вам подойдет  `document.addEventListener`:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("one")});
document.addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("two")});
```

Comment: Спасибо обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Когда Вы прогоняете функцию second через цикл, то  button[i].onclick ==e.onclick. То есть, Вы передаёте метод onclick каждой кнопке  . А в функции first в каждом новом цикле document.onclick() меняет своё значение, и по завершению имеет только одно значение, где е==button[s.length-1]==button[1] , 
Вчера свет вырубили, поэтому не смог ответить. По простому можно, так.

```
    var s = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    //first(s[i], i); //Работает только Button 2.
    second(s[i], i); // Работает нормально.
}

function second(e, i) {
    e.onclick = function(o) {
        o.stopPropagation();
        if (o.target == e || e.contains(o.target)) {
            alert('Открылся Select!');
        }
    }
}
document.onclick = function(o) {
    alert('закрылся Select')
}
```

Просто document.onclick как-то слишком обширно всего лишь для отмены. Подумайте также в сторону addEventListener для document

Comment: спасибо я знаю что я неправильно написал. Как сделать чтобы ТОЛЬКО при нажатие `Button 1` и `Button 2` открывать `Select`, а в другом случае закрывать `Select`